# Появляется лишний отступ margin справа

Tags: html, css

Адаптирую таблицу с корзиной магазина под мобильную версию, когда устанавливаю ширину колонок появляется лишний отступ (выделяется оранжевым как `margin`, но ни как в цифрах не отображается) справа. Ширина таблицы стоит `width: 100%`, и контейнера в которой расположена таблица тоже. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У Вас блок имеет фиксированную ширину меньше, чем ширина родительского блока (таблицы, `tr`, скорее всего унаследовался от `th`). Поэтому выделяется оставшееся пространство (это не `margin`, это вот так свободное место выделяется). Уберите фиксированную ширину родителя — автоматически исчезнет это свободное пространство.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar вы имеете в виду убрать фиксированную ширину у самой таблицы (тег `table`) или блока (блок `div`), в которую она обернута? У меня везде стояло `width: 100%`, поменяла на `width: auto` - проблема не решилась. Теги `th` и `td` у меня имеют одинаковую фиксированную ширину

Comment: Нет, сама обкртка таблицы на это поведение не влияет. Если так, как Вы описываете, то ничего не понятно, что там происходит. Показывайте код (кодом, а не картинкой, HTML и CSS).

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Дело в том, что это страница WordPress. могу смотреть только разметку и стили в devTools браузера.